# meld: Make one part read only

Tags: merge, meld

Up to now I used emacs ediff mode for merging. I tried meld, but could not find a way to make one buffer/file read only. I never merge in two directions, that's way I make one part read only before merging.

Answer (score 1):

The "Merge mode (in development)"  section on the [meld features page](https://meldmerge.org/features.html) calls this Lock down and that kind of functionality doesn't seem to be released yet, beside it not being clear if this can be used outside of merge mode. ( status 2020-08 )

WHat you can do is make the file you don't want to change (temporarily) read-only.
That will give you a lock-icon and a grey-ed out "Save file in this pane" icon next to your filename, and you cannot edit the file in that pane.

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://lukas.zapletalovi.com/2012/09/three-way-git-merging-with-meld.html) can help you I believe. It says

```
[merge]
tool = mymeld
[mergetool "mymeld"]
cmd = meld --diff $BASE $LOCAL --diff $BASE $REMOTE --diff $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE
```

> This is what I call traditional two-way merge with tabs. Now, since I
>   already noted Meld supports three-way merging, there is another
>   option. When “diff3” git conflict style is set, Meld prints “(??)” on
>   the line showing the content from BASE. In this mode, LOCAL and REMOTE
>   files are **read-only** which is also handy.